# PHP Array for hard multilevel items

Tags: php, arrays

i have this array structure and i want to create other array structure with that:

```
array (size=7)
  0 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Dorado' (length=6)
      1 => string '64GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Blanco' (length=6)
      1 => string '32GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Blanco' (length=6)
      1 => string '64GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Madera' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Verde' (length=5)
      1 => string '64GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Madera' (length=6)
  4 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Azul' (length=4)
      1 => string '128GB' (length=5)
      2 => string 'Cristal' (length=7)
  5 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Azul' (length=4)
      1 => string '128GB' (length=5)
      2 => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
  6 => 
    array (size=9)
      0 => string 'Azul' (length=4)
      1 => string '64GB' (length=4)
      2 => string 'Cristal' (length=7)
```

Each array item have a group of characteristics like:

```
0 => string 'Dorado' (length=6)
1 => string '64GB' (length=4)
2 => string 'Plastico' (length=8)
....
0 => string 'Azul' (length=4)
1 => string '128GB' (length=5)
2 => string 'Cristal' (length=7)
```

I need an array that have this values like

Azul=>64GB=>Plastico
128GB=>Cristal

if sub item repeats only write the children value

Azul=>64GB=>Cristal Only adds Cristal because 64GB exists

I have this code in php:

```
foreach ($arrCaracteristicas as $itemMadre => $valueMadre) {
    $NombreNodo = $valueMadre[0];
    if ($NumeroCaracteristicas > 1) {
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $NumeroCaracteristicas - 1; $i++) {
            $NombreCaract = $valueMadre[$i];
            echo "$NombreNodo: $NombreCaract <br>";
            
            array_push( $arrSelectMain[$NombreNodo], $NombreCaract);
            
            if (!isset($arrSelectMain[$NombreNodo][$NombreCaract])) {
                //$arrSelectMain[$NombreNodo]["d"] = $NombreCaract;
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Where $arrCaracteristicas have the long array, and $arrSelectMain have the first level of the array keys:

Code of first level:

```
foreach ($arrCaracteristicas as $item => $value) {
    $arrSelectMain[$value[0]] = $value[0];
}
asort($arrSelectMain);
$arrSelectMain = array_unique($arrSelectMain);
```

This is an image with structure that i want:
https://ibb.co/Q8k198Y

If somebody can help me i will invite a beer in paypal :)

Comment: can you post an exact sample of the input and the exact output you want to get for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, first separate the array into columns and then loop over the items.

```
$first = array_column($items, 0);
$second = array_column($items, 1);
$third = array_column($items, 2);

$output = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($first); $i++) {
        $output[$first[$i]][$second[$i]][] = $third[$i];
}
```

Have a look at the [sample](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cccc310603a0dc8d79a404fb9e6d9b9c01b6424a)

Comment: Wow that works :D, i have two questions, first:
How can i get random number of items, for example in some times are more or less levels, i can get the number of the items, how can i do that?
send me your paypal for invite you a beer!

Comment: Thanks for the offer but upvoting and accepting the answer is good enough for me. :) I am sorry, I don't understand exactly your follow up questions. I'll just throw these here, might be helpful, for getting a random number between 1 and 5, you can use `mt_rand(1,5)`. For getting the count, the function is `count()`;

Comment: Yes of course, but i'snt random number of the value, it's a random number of items, for example: $first = array_column($items, 0); $second = array_column($items, 1); etcetera, its a number of variables

Comment: Maybe this? `count($output['Azul']['128GB']);` it would return 2

Comment: Well, as long as the first three in each of your arrays are made in the same way, 4th, 5th and the rest of the items are simply ignored with the provided solution. If you want to cover the 4th level, just move `$third[$i]` into the array key and use `$fourth[$i]` as the value.